# More powerful but still simple alternative to the gloss package?

Tags: haskell, graphics, 3d, 2d

I've been playing around with "Gloss" for a day now but I feel like my possibilities are very limited.
Can you recommend a more powerful library?
If there is a simple 3D library, I'd like to use it but if it gets significantly more complex then I'm also fine with staying at 2D for the moment. I can't exactly tell you what I expect from the new library but it should be more flexible and provide more (advanced) features.
PS: I'm on Windows 7 64bit if that matters

Comment: What exactly are you looking for when you say more advanced features?

Answer (score 1):

I think the question may be a little vague and "more powerful" is certainly subjective.  But since you mentioned that you were on Windows 7-x64 then I can only guess to point you towards [HGamer3D](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HGamer3D-0.2.1) as a possible solution.  I've heard some good things about it, but I've never used it myself.  In any case there looks to be plenty to chew on there.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenGL](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/OpenGL).

[An introductory tutorial, by Mikael Vejdemo Johansson](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/OpenGLTutorial1),

loosely based on [the tutorial by Sven Eric Panitz](http://www.cs.hs-rm.de/~panitz/hopengl/skript.html).